# Preselect an option for form > select element based on button clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a page which displays several products and each of them have their own "Buy Now" button, however, each button leads to the same contact form (on the same page).

The contact form has a `<select>` element which has the dropdown options of selecting one of the product. Would it be possible to preselect the value of the `<select>` element based on the button that was clicked on the page.

For instance, If a user clicks on the "Buy Now" button for product "ABC", the contact form will be displayed and the value of the "Product" (`<select>`) element would be "ABC"

Form's code, in case anyone wants to look at it:

```
<div class="pop-up">
    <div class="popup-element">

        <img src="img/close.png" id="close-pop-up">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="htmlform" method="post" role="form" action="mailer.php">
            <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="inputPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone/Email">

            <div class="input-group">
                <select name="inputProduct" class="form-control">
                    <option value="None">Select a Product</option>
                    <option value="abc">ABC</option>
                    <option value="def">DEF</option>
                    <option value="ghi">GHI</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <textarea name="inputMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Special requests or custom requirements" rows="3"></textarea>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-query" value="Get a Quote">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
Here's the code for my button:

```
<h2 class="btn-success quote pop-up-button">Book Now</h2>
```

And here's the jQuery for it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open popup
    $('.pop-up-button').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.pop-up').addClass('is-visible');
    });

    //close popup
    $('.pop-up').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('#close-pop-up') || $(event.target).is('.pop-up') ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $('.pop-up').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell not knowing your product's structure, but I presume they somehow hold the corresponding value. I assume you have a structure like this and the product is stored in a `data-product`:

```
<div class="product" data-product="abc">
    <div>ABC</div>
    <h2 class="btn-success quote pop-up-button">Book Now</h2>
</div>
```

Then all you need to do is to get the value of the selected product and set the `select` value to it:

```
$('.product .btn-success').on('click', function() {
    $('.form-control').val($(this).parent().data('product'));
});
```

Here's a [**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/1e4w7ez4/)

**EDIT:**

Explanation: `$('.form-control')` is your select's class and `.val()` refers to its value. We want to set a new value, so the new value goes inside `.val(new_value)`.

The new value comes from the selected product (which we're getting it from a custom data attribute we assigned to the product: `data-product="abc"`. jQuery's `.data('key') returns the`value`assigned to the selector in format of`

`$(this)` - as you said - refers to the `h2` element and the `data-*` assigned to it's parent, so I use `parent()` go to `h2`'s parrent = `div.product` and then get its `data-*` value.

Note 1:The value assigned to the select has to be the value of one of its options or it will have no effect'

Note 2: I used one of your select classes `.form-control`. If more of your form elements have that class, it's better to narrow it down like $('select.form-control') or give your `select` a specific class or id.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much. Using `data-product` attribute is perfect. If it's okay to ask here, would you mind explaining the javascript in line `$('.form-control').val($(this).parent().data('product'));`?

I understand `$(this)` is the <h2> element but how are you extracting the value?

Comment: No problem, I edited the post and added some explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can define a variable when you press the first button and then read it and select with javascript the `<option>` and add the `selected="selected"` attribute.
So, your first buttons should have a variable added to the href like this:

```
  <a href="page1.html?option=1">BTN1</a>
  <a href="page1.html?option=2">BTN2</a>
```

Then you can read the variable using javascript:

```
if(window.location.indexOf("?option=1")!= -1){
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-horizontal option")[optionIndex].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
}
```

Here, `optionIndex` is the index (remember, it starts at 0, not 1) of the option you want to select.

**EDIT: If you'r buttons are in the same page, so there is no reload, is much easier and you can do it like this:**

Say you have:

```
<h2 class="btn" data-option="1">Btn1</h2>
<h2 class="btn" data-option="2">Btn2</h2>

<script>
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    var options = document.querySelectorAll(".form-horizontal option");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", autoSelect);
    };
    function autoSelect (e) {
        var index = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-option");
        options[index].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
</script>
```

This has a few advantages:
1. You don't have to load the 100kb of jQuery.
2. You are using the data attribute that is the right way to specify information in html5

Comment: But wouldn't adding the link change/reload the page? How would I prevent that?

Comment: isn't your button an <a> tag?

Comment: No. I'm sorry I should've mentioned that. My button is an `<h2>` tag with a class of "pop-up" and a jquery which displays the form's div when the button is clicked on. i'll edit the question to include that code as well

Comment: I edited my answer, in case it can be usefull to you